# Error: main.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'http'

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

The `http` module is baked into Node.js, right?  So `require('http');` has to work, right?  Then why does this fail?

`var httpSumo = require('http');`

seems to result in this error:

> main.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'http'

Might there be something in a configuration someplace that's preventing it from loading?  I've done this before.  It has always worked, but here I'm forking from someone else's git.

Comment: What repository are you using?

Comment: Joe, I'm sorry, I'm so new at this...  this should be my repository
https://hub.jazz.net/git/ibmdthompson55/SpeechToSpeech-ibmdthompson55-1537

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I didn't see this before, but the component that's failing is client side, not server side.  So of course it can't open a socket.  d'oh... that' explains it.